# Custom Function as paratemer in MariaDB query

Tags: mariadb, query

I have the following code in Maria DB ,

I want to use my function in a query to create a sequence that starts with the count(*) +1 of a my TABLE1

It gives me an error in the CREATE SEQUENCE query :

```
    CREATE FUNCTION myFuntion() RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
       DECLARE lastID INT DEFAULT 1;
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO lastID FROM TABLE1;
       RETURN lastID+1;
    END;
    
   CREATE SEQUENCE seq101 START WITH myFuntion() INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Error :

> MySqlError { ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
> the right syntax to use near 'myFuntion() INCREMENT BY 1' }

Comment: START value must be numeric literal

Answer (score 1):

**Plan A**  Switch to `AUTO_INCREMENT`  That is, simply an `ALTER TABLE` to change the column to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  It will automatically do the `MAX(id)+1` to get started.

**Plan B** Using `SEQUENCE`:

- The syntax error is because it is expecting a constant there.  A workaround is to build a Stored Procedure to compute the number, construct a string for the `CREATE` statement, then `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` it.
- Caution:  Without `START TRANSACTION ... COMMIT`, a separate connection could grab the "next" id before you can.
- Change from `COUNT(*)+1` to `MAX(id)+1`, just in case there are already gaps in the ids -- due to `DELETEs` or other operations that could create gaps.  (Eg, `INSERT IGNORE`.)